# Aura Component Field Validation Error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation, javascript-controller

I am tryin to handle field validation for a lightning:input field in a custom aura component. I've referenced the [validating fields documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm) with no success. I find my lightning:input component in my JS controller, pull it's value, but when i try to conditionally set the error message, I get an error:

```
Uncaught Action Failed... [Cannot read property 'config' of undefined]"
```

**Here's my component markup:**

```
<aura:component controller="cntrler" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" description="desc" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <aura:attribute name="savedSearchSelected" type="Boolean" default="true" description="Tracks whether the user is filtering a saved search or performing a new search" />

    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.savedSearchSelected == false}">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-1">
            <div class="slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning:input name="search-name" value="{!v.savedSearchName}" placeholder="Name your search, if you'd like" aura:id="search-name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:renderIf>
</aura:component>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```js
({
    saveSearch : function(component, event, helper) {
        var input = component.find('search-name');
        var searchName = input.get('v.value')
        console.log(input, searchName); 
        if(helper.isEmpty(searchName)){
            console.log('empty name');
            //input.set('v.errors',[{message:'Please name your search before saving'}]);
        } else {
            //input.set('v.errors', null);
        }
    }
})
```

The input.set() lines in the controller are what's causing the error. Why am I not able to use this component.set() method when I am successfully retrieving the component (as shown by my console.log and even the .get value from that component in the line prior)

Comment: Are you saying this is your issue -- `input.get('v.value')`? I doubt if that's the one. Is this your exact code? E.g., I see `controller="cntrlr.cls"`, which is syntactically incorrect and I think won't let you save the component.

Comment: I replaced some distinguishing names for privacy. I will update it to make sense. Also, I've updated it to say input.set('') which is where I'm seeing the issue, not input.get(), thanks for pointing that out. I can verify that I get the error **only when the input.set('') lines are not commented out**

Comment: It worked when you removed the comment marks from these lines?
`//input.set('v.errors',[{message:'Please name your search before saving'}]);`
and `//input.set('v.errors', null);`

Comment: So your error is not on `input.get` but `input.set`, right?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, the issue is on the line where you are setting the error on your `lightning:input` component as:

```
input.set('v.errors',[{message:'Please name your search before saving'}]);
```

in this case the error you are receiving is the expected behavior.

`var input = component.find('search-name');` will return a [`lightning:input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) component. And that a `lightning:input` component does not have a property `errors` which can be set here thus resulting in error.

The `errors` attribute was/is only present for `ui:input` as mentioned in [Validating Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm) documentation. The documentation also states that `ui` namespace is being deprecated with API v46.0.

> Components in the ui namespace are deprecated as of API version 46.0

---

So, if you want to set an error message on the `lightning:input` component, you will need to use `setCustomValidity()` here as below:

```
input.setCustomValidity("your message here");
```

Take a look at the *Custom Validity Error Messages* section in the [`lightning:input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) documentation for details.